# Android:show views while progressdialog running

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a Video `Activity` that contains some `TextViews` along with `videoview`. I am loading video from server. Now I want these `textviews` to be shown when `progressdialog` is running. In my case it shows a blank screen with only a progressdialog running and when `video` loading completes it then shows that Textviews.

Comment: Provide source code of your activity

Comment: As @RomanBlack said you should provide us a code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use background color of progressbar as transparent.